# ¿Cómo convertir horas, minutos y segundos a decimales?

Tags: sql

Tengo una columna como propiedad es time osea fecha y hora, pero yo al querer solo horas le hice `convert(char(8), Horario.HoraInicio, 108)` y ahora lo que tengo del `convert` quiero convertirlo en decimales.

Quisiera saber como convertir de `06:00:00` a `6` o `01:30:00` a `1.5`

Answer (score 1):

Si estamos hablando de una columna del tipo `TIME` o una cadena "casteable" a un `TIME` una forma bastante sencilla es calcular la diferencia en segundos desde la hora '00:00:00' y dividirla por 3600 (los segundos de una hora):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST('06:00:00' AS TIME))/3600.0
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST('01:30:00' AS TIME))/3600.0
```

**Muy importante**: Para que la operación no se considere como una división entera, especificamos `3600.0` para forzar el resultado a un número con decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este codigo.

```
select  (substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),campoFecha, 120), 12, 2)*60 + substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),campoFecha, 120), 15, 2))/60.00 as totalHoras
```